# STS: ERROR BrokerService - Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to run my spring web application with Spring Tool Suite (STS) (version  3.2.0.RELEASE) and the embedded VMWare vFabric server.

I get the error:

> ERROR BrokerService - Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb, whilst the temporary data directory: C:\Program Files\sts\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\activemq-data\localhost\tmp_storage only has 37077 mb of usable space

and i cannot start the server.

In the file system i find `C:\Program Files\sts\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE` but i can't even find the mentioned subdirectories, and i cannot understand this message.

What should i check?

Thanks for help.

Comment: this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546730/startup-error-of-embedded-activemq-temporary-store-limit-is-51200-mb

Comment: yes it can be related but i cannot find where activeMQ.xml is, and it now seems the real problem is not this message but the server is not started for some other (unknown) reason

Comment: hard to diagnose from the distance without further information. Maybe also a access rights problem for where the temp file is stored? I've heard that Windows can be very strict with stuff being stored into the "Program Files" area. So maybe try to install STS and tc-Server into a different location with full access rights for the user? Just a wild guess...