# ActiveMQ broker storage usage

Tags: activemq-classic

I have 3 ActiveMQ brokers, out of the three, one broker is running into an issue which says persistent store is full.

## Sample error:

## INFO | Usage(default:store:queue://foo.bar:store) percentUsage=99%, usage=537210471, limit=536870912, percentUsageMinDelta=1%;Parent:Usage(default:store) percentUsage=100%, usage=537210471, limit=536870912,percentUsageMinDelta=1%: Persistent store is Full, 100% of 536870912. Stopping producer (ID: AKUNTAMU-1-31754-1388571228628-1:1:1:1) to prevent flooding queue://foo.bar. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 155s)

I have configured my storeUsage limit as 100GB for persistent messages but when i go and check the disk usage of the kahadb it is more than 100GB (it is 190Gb).
My understanding is kahadb folder contains both the persistent messages plus the journal log files.

Question:
1) Can we query kahadb to see which queue is eating up space?
2) Inside the kahadb folder, how do we segregate the space occupied by messages and other database related files. because everything is data*.log files.
3) for the other 2 brokers, on the activemq web console the store limit used is showing as 0%, confused on this part. so how i validate if its actually zero percent on the other two brokers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we configure ActiveMQ we provide a setting as to how much space on the Disk the MQ should be using,

The settings have 3 parameters

- Memory Usage
- Store Usage
- Temp Usage

Out of which TempUsage is the maximum memory that MQ can use to store the non-persistent messages, you should most probably have this value set to **50GB**(which is 536870912 bytes).
Have a look at this answer on how to find this value
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549226/2551236

I haven't seen this limit being breached, is there no consumer on the queue or some slow consumer? any which ways if you want to increase the limit you can tweak your activemq.xml file as mentioned in the above answer.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!