# How to specify a custom activemq.xml with a Spring embedded ActiveMQ broker?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, jms, activemq-classic

In a Spring Boot application, I use an embedded ActiveMQ broker.

I can configure it with:

- the [Spring Boot ActiveMQ properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQProperties.java),
- the [Broker URI](https://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri),
- the [ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer.html),

but some properties are available only through the [activemq.xml configuration file](https://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration).

How to specify a custom activemq.xml with a Spring embedded ActiveMQ broker?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom ActiveMQ configuration on your classpath and load it with:

```
@Profile("embedded-activemq")
@ImportResource("classpath:embedded-activemq.xml")
@Configuration
  public class EmbeddedActiveMQConfig {
}
```

You will need Spring [NamespaceHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html) for ActiveMQ (not present in spring-boot-starter-activemq):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can then take the official [activemq.xml](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.15.14/assembly/src/release/conf/activemq.xml) corresponding to you version of ActiveMQ and adapt it to the Spring embedded context such as:

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
                http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.15.13.xsd
        ">

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            brokerName="localhost"
            persistent="false"
            useJmx="false"
            enableStatistics="false">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

</beans>
```